# Which music player can write ratings to tags, or: How to not lose my song ratings upon reinstall?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, id3

One thing that has always annoyed massively is that all my ratings get lost when I reinstall my system. And that happens often.
 I know from MediaMonkey for Windows that it is possible to write the rating to tags. Interestingly, when loading the songs into Banshee, for instance, the ratings are recognized in fact!

But apparently, Banshee does not write ratings to the ID3 tag itself.  Which player is capable of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Banshee can do this, but you first need to go to Edit->Preferences and tick the checkbox labelled "Write ratings and play counts to files".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Interesting! That does not work for me! Bug? Does it work for you?

Comment: It works for me. What exactly doesn't work for you? IIRC, Banshee doesn't automatically look back through all of your music and update the ID3 tags when you check that box, but once that box is checked, any future ratings that you make should get written to the file.

Comment: Well I checked it again. Enabled that mode, played a song, closed Banshee, looked at the tag, found that it was not written. Is it possible that it does not work for .flac files?

Comment: @Ingo That's certainly possible - mine are all .ogg and .mp3

Answer (score 0):

- Banshee
- Songbird (no longer officially supported for Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Also - [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) can (optionally) save ratings into many audio formats.